# Push notification stop working in xcode once the app is uploaded to TestFlight

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications, apple-developer

I manage to get Push Notification work in ionic ios. But after releasing to TestFlight, push notification work in TestFlight but not in xcode although it was working fine before that.

I'm using cordova 9 Firebase FCM for push notification with the following apple certificates:

- Apple Sandbox Push Services
- Distribution Managed
- iOS Distribution
- Development

I'm using web server to set payload

```
function send_notification ($token, $message, $title)
{
    $path_to_firebase_cm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        
    $fields = array(
        'to' => $token,
        'notification' => array('title' => $title, 'body' => $message, 'click_action' => 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY'),
        'data' => array('message' => $message, 'title' => $title),
        'sound' => 'default'
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=AAAAf.............'
    );      
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_firebase_cm); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);      
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

In app.component.ts page

```
  {
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.badge.set(this.notiunread);

    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

        const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
        if(SigninData!=null){
            console.log("have data");
            this.router.navigate(["/tabs"], { skipLocationChange: true });
        } else {
            console.log("no data");
            this.router.navigate(["/landing"], { skipLocationChange: true });
        }



    //  this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');
      this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
        console.log(token);
      }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

      // ionic push notification example
      this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.wasTapped) {
          console.log('Received in background');
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab1/notification']);
        } else {
          this.backgroundMode.enable();
          this.badge.set(this.notiunread);
          console.log('Received in foreground');
          this.call(data);
        }
      });

      // refresh the FCM token
      this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
        console.log(token);
      }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });



    });

    this.providersservices.getObservable().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('Data received', data);
        this.pic = data.pic;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.phone = data.number;
    });

    const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
    if(SigninData!=null){
        const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
        this.userData.id=SigninData.mem_id;
        this.userData.token=SigninData.token;
        this.userData.plid = "7";
        this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "memberencrypt").subscribe((result) =>{
            this.data = result;
            this.items = this.data.data;
            this.code = this.items.mem_id;
            console.log(result);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }


 this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "badgenotification").subscribe((result) =>{
    this.data3 = result;
    this.items3 = this.data3.data;
    this.notiunread = this.items3.length;
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
      console.log(this.notiunread);
    this.badge.set(this.notiunread);

    if(Array.isArray(this.items3))
      this.exist3 = this.items3[0].exist;
    else
      this.exist3 = this.items3.exist;
    console.log(result);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  });


    this.providersservices.postData(this.userData, "pointshare").subscribe((result) =>{
        this.data1 = result;
        this.items1 = this.data1.data;
        this.point = this.items1.pl_value;
        console.log(result);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });

    if(this.pic==undefined&&this.name==undefined&&this.name==undefined){
        const SigninData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("signindata"));
        if(SigninData!=null){
            this.pic = SigninData.mem_photo;
            this.name = SigninData.mem_name;
            this.phone = SigninData.mem_phonetcode + SigninData.mem_phone;
        }
    }
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'custom');



{
    //this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'ml']);
    //this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
 }

  }
```

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.2.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.11
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.15
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.15
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, browser 5.0.4, ios 6.1.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 28 other plugins)

System:

   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v10.14.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 7.21.1
   OS      : macOS Monterey
   Xcode   : Xcode 13.4 Build version 13F17a
```

Please help!

Comment: Check your build configuration if you have different keys, because TestFlight and AppStore user Release version, and Xcode by default Debug, you can change it for testing on the local machine, select project and open Edit Scheme

Comment: All build configuration are Debug except for profile and archive are release version. I changed to Debug but still the same issue.

Comment: are you can supplement the answer with code examples of how you realize push notification, where you setup some settings and etc.

Comment: Can you please refer to the question? I put notification code that I use and more details

Comment: I did check all docs of ionic and can say that I can't help you with that, have no experience with non-native technologies, but I find two examples that can help you check this < https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUr8pw0nO7Y > and this doc < https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase >

Comment: I have the same issue? How did you solve that?

Comment: Hi submariner, try to uninstall the app from your phone then run your app again. This is work in my case..

Comment: let me know if you sill facing the problem